# What's the meaning of the ending of "Another Earth"?

Tags: plot-explanation, another-earth

At the end of the movie ["Another Earth"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1549572), Rhoda encounters herself in front of her house's garage. It's very obvious that almost the same events did occur on Earth 2 and her mirror did travel to Earth 1 which both suggests that the synchronicity didn't break 4 years ago when Earth 2 was discovered but it also suggests that the synchronicity is broken because Rhoda from Earth 1 didn't travel to Earth 2.

How should we interpret it?

Answer (score 4):

No, It's the opposite and it's easy to see the difference between "Rhoda 1" and  "Rhoda 2"s clothes and overall look which suggests that the synchronicity did break and "Rhoda 2" didn't kill John's family, didn't go to the prison but rather went to MIT and had a successful life.

[image]

Comment: Do you think that they would send Rhoda 1 to Earth 2 with her everyday clothing. Btw even Rhoda 2 didn't travel with that clothing but rather changed her clothing after arrival. Anyway if that would be the case then I have to ask why Rhoda 2 did travel to Earth 1? Why was she chosen on Earth 2? It can't be answered with synchronicity (You already suggest for that scenario that the synchronicity has to be broken.)

Comment: But the synchronicity must've been broken or else Rhoda 1 will be at earth 2 when Rhoda 2 at earth 1! Anyway, It seems like this question has been asked before in "scifi exchange" and it has a lot of good answers http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11437/what-is-the-meaning-to-the-ending-of-another-earth (Most of the answers suggest that the synchronicity did break and John is responsible for "Rhoda 2" coming to earth 1 somehow, but there are other theories and it's worth a read!)

Comment: After reading the suggestions on Scifi.SE I see that the only logical explanation is Rhoda 2 to be sent back to Earth1 by John 1. I'll select your answer as the solution if you add this detail to your answer.

Comment: I'm really not comfortable adding this details since it's just a theory/guess (and not even my guess), still you yourself can post an answer adding all the details you found that sufficiently answer the question then accept that answer.